# Which is best strategy of reboot of Linux node in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

a) Plain reboot command.
or
b) Execute kubectl drain and then reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely option-2 using `kubectl drain` approach.

*Before reboot:*

`kubectl drain $NODENAME` will gracefully terminate all pods on the node while marking the node as unschedulable.

*After reboot:*

Once the reboot is done and its good to go then make the node schedulable again: `kubectl uncordon $NODENAME`.

Please go through [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#maintenance-on-a-node) documentation.

Directly running plain reboot on node, will affect all the pods running on that node so don't recommends that approach.

Comment: Is it advisable to do if downtime is brief also ? i.e changing some config fle and then reboot.

Comment: If there is downtime, then definitely yes.

Comment: So for normal reboot drain is not required.

Comment: If its not a production k8s cluster and you don't care if your few of the application pods running on that node goes down for sometime then its fine to reboot the node right away.

Comment: @SumitKumar not only about downtime, but also to reduce the possibility of data loss or corruption due to abnormal termination, especially in statefulsets. Whenever you have the control (like in this case), you should always terminate processes gracefully, giving them to hand over/cleanup their resources. To this use case it translates as cordon/drain, then reboot.